# US and UK based site how to handle

Tags: html, redirect, geolocation

We have 2 sets of prices, $ and £'s.

How best can I handle this.

Should I have a folder with the US site in so when users click on the US flag they go to mydomain.com/us and then navigate from there.

Or is there something simpler I can do?

The HTML site passes users over to our client system when ordering so currency conversion etc isnt needed. Just want advice on how to handle displaying a site in dollars and pounds.

Comment: Are we talking about ASP.NET here? PHP? What is it? Or is it just a set of HTML files you have?

Comment: Just html files with possible addition of PHP for contact form etc. We only have pricing in US $ and UK pounds and its looks horrible to have them both on the same page.

Was thinking of a flag for UK and for US so users can select.

Comment: The simplest thing you can do is to request payment by a natural produce. Ask your customers to send you timber, food (preferably rice or grain) and fur. That's independent of whether your customers are in the US or in the UK.  No need for complicated sub-domains or HTML redirections.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a country field on your user's table you could use this value to determine what symbol and prices to show.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to keep it really simple without any server-side page generation use a bit of JavaScript.  Pick a default currency and allow the user to click US or UK to switch to the other one.  Javascript can be used to set a cookie so that when the user revisits the website, or views other pages, you can automatically set the preferred currency.

There are a few different ways to perform the conversion, and it probably depends most on how you do the conversion yourself.  If you are just going by a current exchange rate store the prices in one currency for each item in a table and then have it apply the exchange rate as part of your conversion function.

Comment: Well the HTML site will pass to our client portal so that handles all the payments/currency etc. Its purely just about displaying the price on the home page and allowing users to basically select which site they want to view.